# npm install required after upgrading node/npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to understand if it is necessary to run a npm install after upgrading node/npm from 6.x to 8.x. If so, can you please explain why this is done? I had a hard time finding some documentation around this.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least run `npm rebuild`.

Some packages may choose to do things differently in a different Node.js environment, particularly when it comes to binary modules.